# Как сделать так, чтоб мигающий курсор был после цифры "996"

Tags: java, android

Есть editText, в него водим только цифры (номер телефона)

Activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="8"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        android:hint="996XXX-XX-XX-XX"
        android:maxLength="12" />
```

Main.Java

```
editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
this.editTextPhone.setText("996");
```

Answer (score 3):

попробуй это

```
 editTextPhone.setSelection(3);
```